# How do I store a Firestore document locally?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I have a Firestore document that changes infrequently and is used as a lookup table in many different places in my app.  It is my understanding that when I do a get for the document it is always performing a server query, even if the data in the document hasn't changed.  The local cache is only used when the server is unavailable.

Since the document changes infrequently I would like to do something like this...

1) When the app starts, get the document and store it locally.

2) Setup a listener so that if the document changes the local copy is updated.

3) When the local copy is updated broadcast this change to any widget that may be using the document.

This is the way I wish Firestore worked by default.

Is this a good idea?  Any suggestions on how to implement this?

Comment: What did you read that suggests there is no existing local cache for documents?  The documentation suggests otherwise: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline

Comment: There is a local document cache for when the server is unreachable.  However I would like to refer to the document cache first always rather than making a new server request each time the data is needed.  This is because this particular document changes infrequently.  The majority of the time the cache is still valid.

Comment: What behavior are you observing that suggests that the local cache isn't being used in the case you propose?

Comment: The run trace shows a HTTP query and my performance monitoring does too.  And the documentation says the local cache is used when the server is unreachable.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure how to access the local cache directly, but if you can access the document via the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api#making_rest_calls) you could use the document's URL along with the [network_resource](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/network_resource) package. If you _can_ access the doc this way I'd be happy to write a quick example.

Comment: Please edit the question to demonstrate the sequence of observations that suggest the local cache is not used for queries, especially when the cache is up to date with the server at the time of the request.  Full reproduction steps are preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing.  It was actually fairly straight forward.  I implemented this as a static class and not sure if that's the best approach.  But I like everything else.

I created a class that sets up a listener for the document and also provides a stream for when it is updated.  As a bit of side work my class also parses the document into a Map and sorts the games.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:pari/game.dart';

class Schedule {
  static Map<String, Game> games = Map<String, Game>();

  static StreamController<Map<String, Game>> _onUpdateController = StreamController.broadcast();
  static Stream get onUpdate => _onUpdateController.stream;

  static void setupListener() {
    print('setupListener');

    DocumentReference reference = Firestore.instance.collection('schedule').document('2018');
    reference.snapshots().listen((documentSnapshot) {
      print('listen begin');

      List<Game> sortedList = List<Game>();
      documentSnapshot.data.values.forEach((value) {
        Game game = Game.fromMap(value);
        sortedList.add(game);
      });
      sortedList.sort((a,b) => a.startTime.compareTo(b.startTime));

      games.clear();
      sortedList.forEach((game) {
        games.addAll({game.key: game});
      });

      _onUpdateController.add(games);

      print('listen end');
      print('games: ${games.length}');
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Where did you end up calling setupListener()?

Comment: When my app initializes.